# Is there a limit to the number of options an Activiti dynamic table can handle?

Tags: activiti

I am using Activiti 1.3. I have a workflow which requires a user action. It displays a dynamic table which has 25 options that user can select from. When I select more than 20 options the display of the dynamic table refreshes automatically and shows only 4 options. Is there a limit to the number of values you can have in a dynamic table?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a restriction (or potential bug) in the declaration of the table.
However, the renderer simply creates a standard HTML table, as such, there is no actual limit to the number of rows and columns.

Enterprise Edition 1.3 is over a year old and there have been a large number of fixes and enhancements in the latter versions, I would strongly suggest upgrading.

Greg